# How to call - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame function?

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I am creating a `UIView` class . in the implementation there is a function

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
```

I am adding a button in the class which is used to reload the class.

I would like to call the class initialization function when the button is pressed so that the view is refreshed and it comes back to its intialization state.

Is there a function which can be used to roll back the view to its intialized state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not call `-init` methods more then once for the same object.

The solution for your problem however is simple - move all your setting properties code to a separate function, e.g. `-setupDefaultProperties` and call it in your initWithFrame method and whenever you want to reset the view to its initial state